# How to use strapi's components to render dynamic data in remix?

Tags: server-side-rendering, strapi, remix, remix.run, headless-cms

im building a simple corporate website with a frontpage, about, blog, single blog posts.

If i create components in strapi, i can just render them with remix from the data i get from remix loaders.

**I would like to create a teaser component that fetches 3 of the newest blog posts no matter where i put the component inside strapi.**

With my current understanding of remix, i can only fetch through loaders if i want to stay with ssr.

Thanks for helping out!!!

my loader function:

```
export async function getPageBySlug(slug) {
  const token = process.env.STRAPI_API_TOKEN;

  if (!token)
    throw new Error("The Strapi API Token environment variable is not set.");

  const path = `/pages`;
  const options = { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } };

  const urlParamsObject = {
    filters: { slug },
    populate: {
      thumbnail: { fields: ["url"] },
      seo: { populate: "*" },
      sections: { populate: "*" },
    },
  };

  const baseUrl = getStrapiURL();
  const page = await fetchAPI(path, urlParamsObject, options);

  return {
    page: page.data[0],
    baseUrl: baseUrl,
    slug: slug,
  };
}
```

thats my front page

```
export default function Home() {
const { page } = useLoaderData();
const { attributes } = page || {}; // Destructure attributes if page exists

    if (attributes) {
        const { sections } = attributes;
        return (
            <main>
                {sections.map((section, index) => sectionRenderer(section, index))}
            </main>
        );
    } else {
        return <Error />;
    }
```

and here is the sectionRenderer:

```
import Hero from "../components/Hero";
import Teaser from "../components/Teaser";

export function sectionRenderer(section, index) {
    switch (section.\__component) {
        case "sections.hero":
            return \<Hero key={index} data={section} /\>;
        case "sections.teaser":
            return \<Teaser key={index} data={section} /\>;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You told us what you're trying to do. But what you're unable to do is not clear. I'm not sure how to help.

Comment: How do I fetch my strapi cms inside those flexible components with SSR in mind. Do I need to do something with useFetcher, what’s the best practice for fetching data outside of routes.

Comment: @emot1onz For SSR to work, you have to load data from loader. Either you can use root loader to route loader to accomplish that. For better performance, you can pass promise from loader and load data with Async Await inside of component.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to create a teaser component that fetches 3 of the newest blog posts no matter where i put the component inside strapi.

```
import { useLoaderData } from "@remix-run/react"

export async function loader() {
    return json(await fakeDb.blogPosts.findAll())
    // sort and return
}

export default function BlogPosts() {
    const posts = useLoaderData<typeof loader>()
    // ...
    return posts.map(post => <Post {...post} ../>
}
```

Within your componentRender/sectionRenderer/renderer component render hierarchy (align with Strapi) place on page